# Handling incorrect url in react router v5

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, react-router

I wanted to show the `ErrorPage` for the incorrect URL. Common way is to add a "catch-all" `Route` path (*) at the end.

```
<Route path="/" exact>
  <Home />
</Route>
<Route path="/:id">
  <Content />
</Route>
<Route path="*">
  <ErrorPage />
</Route>
```

I need to do some validation like I need to see whether the `id` exists in my list of ids or not. Based on that I should render the `<Content />`.

Let say, user enters `"www.example.com/**invalidId**"`. In this case, `Route` format passes and renders the content component. Adding too that I need to check the if the `id` exists in my list.

I have listed 2 ways below to achieve this result. What is the recommended way? Or is there any better solution to this?

1. Do the `id` check in the `Content` component and render it only if the `id` is valid else render the `ErroPage`.
2. Add an `"/error"` route path `<Route path="/error"><Error /></Route>`.

   Do the `id` check in `Content` component, if the id is valid render the component else redirect to `"/error"` route path which in turn renders the error page component (one downfall in this method is, user entered incorrect url will be lost)

I'm using `react-router@5`.

Comment: I assume what you are trying to do is that is user hits `/:id` route, you want to check if the `id` exists, if it doesn't you want to indicate that to the user? If yes then you can validate the `id` exists, if it doesn't show a message to the user that this `id` doesn't exists. No need to redirect but even if you do redirect to an error page, that won't be much of a problem too.

Comment: I rephrased my question a bit. And yes, i am aware that both are possible. I wanted to know the recommended way. what is the best way to achieve this?

Comment: In my opinion there is no way that is better than the other, you can choose what seems more appropriate to you for your application. Personally, i will choose the one where i show the message to the user that the given id doesn't exists.